# Using OpenGL functions in object constructor without context loaded

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

I have a problem with creating object before the context is initialized. My code looks something like this:

```
..
Vertex vertices[] = { ... } // declaration of object Vertices
Mesh mesh(vertices, sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(vertices[0]));
..
..
void onDisplay()
{
    ..
    mesh.Draw();
    ..
}
void init() { .. }
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ..
    glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay);
    ..
}
```

As I have read on [OpenGL site](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#The_Object_Oriented_Language_Problem), the problem is that an Object is created before the context is initialized (because of the code in constructor). If i would put the "mesh" and "vertices" in "void init()", that would solve the problem, but I couldn't use method "mesh.Draw()" in "void onDisplay" - because the object mesh is not global, it is declared only in init().

On OpenGL site they tell about how to fix this, but I really don't understand what I should do.

The solutions from OpenGL site are these:

- Do not use constructors/destructors to initialize/destroy OpenGL objects. Instead, use member functions of these classes for these purposes. This violates RAII principles, so this is not the best course of action.
- Have your OpenGL object constructors throw an exception if a context has not been created yet. This requires an addition to your context creation functionality that tells your code when a context has been created and is active.
- Create a class that owns all other OpenGL related objects. This class should also be responsible for creating the context in its constructor.

Solution 1 is not recommended, solution 2 wouldn't help me (at least I think not) and I have no idea how I would make solution 3

Comment: _"but I really dont understand what I should do."_ What in particular you didn't understand?

Comment: I did not understand solution 3. I think that solution 2 wouldn't help me and solution 1 is not recommended as they said.

Comment: _"I did not understand solution 3."_ What are these solutions actually? [Please edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29545120/edit) and show the proposed solutions, and what in particular you're missing. Links pointing to off-site resources are likely not to be followed by readers of your question (like me). Also if you're linking do it precisely (Did you mean this particular [chapter](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#OOP_and_hidden_binding) there?).

Comment: Updated my question. I was talking about chapter [The Object Oriented Language Problem](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#The_Object_Oriented_Language_Problem)

Comment: For my understanding the 3rd solution proposes creating a kind of factory class, that is responsible to initialize the context, and hand out any further class instances that need to have it initialized.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? You get a blank screen I'm assuming. I recommend running it through the debugger and go through the program's execution step by step. Also, if you have GL code in your ctors and these objects are global variables, their ctors will be called before you enter main so you should keep pointers instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I am now trying to do. Like you said they are global variables and are called before main, so there the problem. I have no idea how to work with pointers in this case. Could you please describe what I should do?
Also you asked what happens when I run the code - nothing it does not build because I am using GL methods without GL context loaded (or at least thats what I think is wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `vertices` and `mesh` to be (smart) pointers and construct the objects in `main()` after you secure a GL context.

If you don't want to change your existing code (`.` to `->` for member access) you can call them `verticesPtr` and `meshPtr` and create local references (`Mesh& mesh = *meshPtr;`) at the top of the functions where you reference them.

Comment: So I tried to figure this on my own, sadly with no luck. I am really new to C++ so I don't understand pointers and how to work with them that much.
What you are saying is that I should change declaration of `mesh` and `vertices` to be pointers:
`Vertex* verticesPtr[];` and `Mesh* meshPtr;`
But then how do I construct them in my `main()`?